# wso2 carbon 4.1 - how to configure to use company proxy

Tags: wso2

Where do I configure carbon to use a proxy server (for example to access features)?

I have searched for files containing "http.proxyHost" in the `CARBON_HOME` folder, but nothing was found.  I tried adding `-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888` to the java command line in `wso2server.sh`, but I get this error after a few minutes after trying to Find Features:

```
[2013-06-03 14:00:53,897] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui.RepositoryAdminServiceClient} -  Error occured while quering installable features
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error occured while quering installable features
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:367)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.stub.RepositoryAdminServiceStub.getInstallableFeatures(RepositoryAdminServiceStub.java:1775)
```

My proxy server logs have no record of it being accessed by carbon.

Answer (score 1):

The config file is located at `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`.  In this file you'll find an element named `<NetworkAuthenticatorConfig>`. You have to specify proxy host/port etc there. It contains some comments in line to help how to configure it.

Comment: how is this configured?  The comments only show how to configure a username and password.  How do I specify the proxy host and port?  What are the tag names that I must use?

Comment: just noticed there's an easier way to pass it as a command line param, try this out: "nohup ./wso2server.sh -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888"

Comment: Thanks - will give that a try.  I think the proxy setup is a red herring as I hit a similar issue trying to install from a local p2 repo.

Comment: btw if what you want is to install features and finding it difficult to do it through a proxy, an alternative way is to download the archive to the local file system from here http://dist.wso2.org/products/carbon/4.1.0/p2-repo.zip  and then installing from it.

Comment: For some reason I am unable to install even from a local file system repo.  I have raised a JIRA for it: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14127